# Require user to hover over picture for certain amount of time

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to enlarge a picture after the user hovers over for a specific amount of time.

This is for an ionic application

```
ion-grid {
    padding: 0;
    ion-col {
        padding: 0;
        &:hover {

            width: 30vw;
        }
    }
}
```

I want the picture to enlarge after the user has hovered over the picture for at least .1 or fewer seconds to prevent all pictures from enlarging while passing over the pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `transition-delay` for this.

> The `transition-delay` property specifies when the transition effect will start.
>   The `transition-delay` value is defined in seconds (s) or milliseconds (ms).

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp).

I copied a small example (with default CSS so it does work on SO).

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition-property: width;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

div:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The transition-delay Property</h1>

<p>Hover over the div element below, to see the transition effect (Note that the transition effect will wait 1 second before starting):</p>

<div></div>
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition-delay).